# Compute the integral $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{y-x}{x}\big)^2}dx$.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration

I am trying to find the distribution of $Y$ when $X \sim \text{U}(0,1)$ and $Y|X \sim \text{N}(X,X^2)$. I have done some calculations and found that

\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)&=\int_{0}^{1}f_{(Y,X)}(y,x)dx\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}f_{(Y|X)}(y|x)f_{X}(x)dx\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{1} f_{\text{N}(x,x^2)}(y|x)f_{\text{U}(0,1)}(x)dx\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi x^2}}e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2x^2}} dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{y-x}{x}\big)^2}dx\\\\
\end{align*}

but I can't see how I can continue from there.

Comment: I am not convinced that there is a closed form

Comment: I found only for $y=1$ is: $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2 e}}
   \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\frac{\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right
   )}{2 \sqrt{2 e \pi }}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk  Hmm maybe that is harder than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $u = 1/x$, you get:

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \int_a^b u \exp \left[-\dfrac{1}{2}(uy-1)^2 \right] (-u^2)\, du,$$

with $a=\infty$ (probably) and $b=1$. Then, with $uy -1 = w$, you get:

$$\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\, y^4}  \int_c^d (w+1)^3 \exp \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}w^2 \right)\, dw,$$

with $c=\infty$ and $d=y-1$. From there, you can do the integral, although you will get the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html).